# Remote SSH commands not working in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, session, ssh, remote-execution

Regardless of why, I am trying to write a script that will let me send a command to various addresses.  There is a shared key for the user, so there is no need for logging in.  But this isn't working.

So, the following will not work...

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=$1
shift
args="'$@'"
cmd="ssh user@$ip -C $args"
output=$($cmd)
```

If I execute it with the following:

```
./myscript.sh 10.0.1.2 /bin/ls -l /var
```

I get the error of "ls -l /var: No such file or directory"

If I run that command (ssh user@10.0.1.2 -C '/bin/ls -l /var'), it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?  These are the same installs of RHEL6.

Comment: This is [BashFAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). You cannot put commands with quotes into strings. It does not work. More to the point you don't need to do this. Either use `"$@"` directly if you want the arguments as individual words or use `"$*"` to get the arguments as a single "word".

Comment: Thanks.  It's more there as a test case, as I was echoing out the $args variable.  But thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the quotes were confusing bash.  The following works...

```
ip=$1
shift
$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 User@$ip "$@")
```